# Realm writes make NSColorPanel lag

Tags: swift, realm, mac-catalyst

In my Catalyst app, I'm spawning an `NSColorPanel` with a callback using code from the Mac Helpers repository.

```
@interface IPDFMacColorPanel : NSObject

+ (void)showColorPanelWithColorChangeHandler:(void(^)(UIColor *color))colorChangeHandler;

/// Hides the color picker panel and removes the colorChangeHandler observer
+ (void)hide;

+ (void)removeColorChangeHandlerObserver;

@end

@interface NSColorPanel_Catalyst : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedColorPanel;

- (void)makeKeyAndOrderFront:(id)sender;
- (void)orderFront:(id)sender;
- (void)orderOut:(id)sender;

- (void)setTarget:(id)target;
- (void)setAction:(SEL)action;

- (UIColor *)color;

@end

@interface IPDFMacColorPanel ()

@property (nonatomic,copy) void(^colorChangeHandler)(UIColor *color);

@end

@implementation IPDFMacColorPanel

+ (instancetype)sharedPanel
{
    static IPDFMacColorPanel *panel = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        panel = [IPDFMacColorPanel new];
    });
    return panel;
}

+ (NSColorPanel_Catalyst *)colorPanel
{
    return [NSClassFromString(@"NSColorPanel") performSelector:@selector(sharedColorPanel)];
}

+ (void)showColorPanelWithColorChangeHandler:(void(^)(UIColor *color))colorChangeHandler
{
    IPDFMacColorPanel *observer = [IPDFMacColorPanel sharedPanel];
    observer.colorChangeHandler = colorChangeHandler;

    NSColorPanel_Catalyst *colorPanel = [self colorPanel];
    [colorPanel setTarget:observer];
    [colorPanel setAction:@selector(colorChange:)];
    [colorPanel orderFront:nil];
}

+ (void)hide
{
    [[self colorPanel] orderOut:nil];
    [self removeColorChangeHandlerObserver];
}

+ (void)removeColorChangeHandlerObserver
{
    [IPDFMacColorPanel sharedPanel].colorChangeHandler = nil;
}

- (void)colorChange:(NSColorPanel_Catalyst *)colorPanel
{
    if (self.colorChangeHandler) self.colorChangeHandler(colorPanel.color);
}

@end
```

I spawn it like this:

```
IPDFMacColorPanel.show { (color) in
    if let color = color {
        self.saveColor(color)
    }
}
```

And then write it to Realm:

```
public func saveColor(_ color: UIColor) {
    try! realm.write {
        let converted = ColorUtility.convert(color: color)
        if let green = converted["green"] {
            self.restaurant.green = green
        }
        if let red = converted["red"] {
            self.restaurant.red = red
        }
        if let blue = converted["blue"] {
            self.restaurant.blue = blue
        }
        if let alpha = converted["alpha"] {
            self.restaurant.alpha = alpha
        }
    }
}
```

However, what happens is, because I get so many callbacks, Realm is writing a lot of colors, making the color panel lag. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: You're not writing a lot of data there so Realm performance should not be an issue. Are you writing data continuously - perhaps as the user is sliding around a color wheel for example so the code is called many times per second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coalesce the writes on the Objective-C side.

```
// new property - add after `@interface IPDFMacColorPanel` line
@property (nonatomic,copy) UIColor *pendingNewColor;

- (void)colorChange:(NSColorPanel_Catalyst *)colorPanel
{
    if (self.pendingNewColor) {
        self.pendingNewColor = colorPanel.color;
    } else {
        self.pendingNewColor = colorPanel.color;
        [self performSelector:@selector(doUpdateColor:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
    }
}

- (void)doUpdateColor:(id)ignore {
    UIColor *color = self.pendingNewColor;
    self.pendingNewColor = nil;
    if (self.colorChangeHandler) self.colorChangeHandler(color);
}
```

When the color is changed, if a pending color exists, it assumes that the doUpdateColor: message will be sent within 0.4 seconds and just updates the pending color, otherwise it sets the pending color and schedules the doUpdateColor: message to be sent.

This solution trades away some apparent responsiveness. You can also do something similar on the receiving Swift side, by storing the color *somewhere* and just not writing it to Realm for a short while, which would maintain immediate responsiveness, but if something was using the color through reading the just-written values from Realm, there would still be a delay there.